# Extracting lines of a text file between delimiters into a list Python

Tags: python

I have a large text file with lines in this format:

```
DELIM
filename1
information
information
DELIM
filename2
information
information
information
information
DELIM
```

and so on, where the amount of data in between the delimiters varies.
How do I go about writing everything between the delimiters as a list?

Comment: Can you give a (small) example? Is there anything structurally different about the file names and the "information"?

Comment: the filenames are all "*.h" or "*.cpp" and the information are all function names

Answer (score 2):

Provided that `DELIM` cannot be found in the in-between lines, you could do that quite easily by:

- reading your file fully (doesn't work that well if your file has 20Tb of data in it but ok for reasonably-sized files)
- applying `str.split` on `DELIM`
- splitting each block and filtering blanks (artifacts of `split`) in a list comprehension

My proposal:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = [x.split() for x in f.read().split("DELIM") if x]

print(lines)
```

result with your input (as a list of lists of lines):

```
[['filename1', 'information', 'information'], ['filename2', 'information', 'information', 'information', 'information']]
```

Edit: with a big file, you could use `itertools.groupy` as follows (avoids reading the file at once)

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = [list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(f,key=lambda x : x.strip()=="DELIM") if not k]
```

`groupby` groups the non-delim lines together and the delim lines together as well, with a `True/False` key: we filter out the `True` key with corresponds to `DELIM` groups and convert to `list`, to reach the same value as in the previous code, only we don't need to read the file beforehand, so it would work with a huge file as well.

Comment: What about using `itertools.groupby`?

Comment: This doesn't properly filter out lines before the first or after the last DELIM. `foo\nDELIM\nDELIM\nbar` should return `[]` (or arguably `[[]]`).

Comment: @PeterWood that would be better, yes. Edited & added that solution.

Comment: a dict with filename as key, subs as a list as a value would be better.